# Google Cloud Storage cost effectiveness for small files?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a lot of small unstructured json files (less than 1K each) I want to store on Google cloud storage somehow (using streaming). I would prefer to avoid putting them into zip files (I think) since I'm thinking of using Apache Drill to perform queries against them. Would it be more cost effective to merge multiple json documents together rather than storing them one by one? (I assume that writing the files in batches would be a good thing regardless if they're merged or stored separately)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well...maybe. It depends on your usage pattern.

GCS does not have a per-object charge. Instead, it charges per Gigabyte stored per month. Breaking the files up won't affect that at all.

However, GCS also charges a per-operation fee. At time of writing, every 10,000 downloads will cost you a penny, and every 10,000 uploads will cost you a dime. If you only have a few thousand files or only access a few files at a time, this might not make a big difference, but if you need to download all of the files frequently, or if you need to replace them frequently, and you're doing millions or billions of separate uploads per day, suddenly using a few big files instead could save you a lot of money.

If you can estimate how many downloads and uploads you'll be doing under each scenario, Google provides a calculator to let you know what it will cost: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

Comment: If I upload a 50 kb small image — will that cost me only 50 kb? I read [some docs](https://blog.scaleway.com/2019/object-storage-how-it-works/) about another object storage, Scaleway's, and there I find: *"Minimal size of a part: 5MB"* which to me sounds as if they'd charge for 5 MB although I only uploaded 50 kb. — But that'd be Scaleway; GCS might work differently?

Comment: No, there's no 5MB thing in GCS. If you store 1.07 billion 1 byte files for one month, your monthly storage cost should be for about 1 gibibyte-months of storage.

That said, storing billions of single byte files in GCS would likely not be the optimal storage solution for other reasons (Cloud BigTable might be a better choice for that), but there's no billing overhead for the cost of storing the objects.

Comment: @ Brandon — that's great to hear :- ) Thanks for the quick reply (4 years after the question was posted)